# How can I climb in the cold?

Tags: a-short-hike

I just got to a snowy area of the park, and when I use up my stamina, I can't recover it; my golden feathers are frozen until I descend and warm up. Is it possible to recover your golden feathers in the cold, or will I need to climb more conservatively at higher altitudes?

[image: 6 frozen feathers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cold, just being on the ground is not enough. However, throughout the trail up to the peak you can find various sources of heat (hot springs, campfires, etc). Warming yourself will restore your stamina.

[image: screenshot of hot springs]